# Using a struct property in ForEach doesn't work

Tags: swift, swiftui

This does not work:
`Text(alarmEntry.description)`

But this does:
`Toggle(isOn: alarmEntry.enabled){Text(verbatim: "This works...")}`

I can't figure it out, just starting with Swift...

```
import SwiftUI


struct TimeOfDay {
    var hour: Int
    var minute: Int
    
    func decribe() {
        print("\(hour):\(minute)")
    }
}

struct AlarmEntry: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var timeHours: Int
    var timeMinutes: Int
    var description: String
    var type: String  // Sound or Haptic
    var typeDefinition: String  // Sound type or Haptics
    var enabled: Bool
    
    func describe() {
        print("Time: \(timeHours):\(timeMinutes), Desc: \(description), Type: \(type), TypeDefinition: \(typeDefinition), Enabled: \(enabled)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // UI Variables
    @State private var alarmEntries =
        [
            AlarmEntry(timeHours: 6, timeMinutes: 45, description: "Alarm number 1", type: "Haptic", typeDefinition: "Shake.Shake.Shake", enabled: false),
            AlarmEntry(timeHours: 14, timeMinutes: 45, description: "Alarm number 2", type: "Haptic", typeDefinition: "Shake.Shake.Shake", enabled: false),
            AlarmEntry(timeHours: 10, timeMinutes: 00, description: "Alarm number 3", type: "Haptic", typeDefinition: "Shake.Shake.Shake", enabled: true)
        ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach($alarmEntries) { alarmEntry in
            Text(alarmEntry.description)
            Toggle(isOn: alarmEntry.enabled){
                Text(verbatim: "This works...")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: alarmEntry.enabled is used with the $ inside the Toggle to create a 2 way binding to the enabled property of the AlarmEntry

Comment: struct when the toggle is changed it will update the enabled property in the original alarmEntries array

Comment: Doesn't work here, gives a different error:  Cannot find '$alarmEntry' in scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a read-write binding property to `ForEach` and each element is a type of `Binding<AlarmEntry>`.

1. `Text(alarmEntry.description)`. The text component takes default input as a String and you're sending a `Binding`, it's not the data type required. You can change to `Text(alarmEntry.wrappedValue.description)`
2. `Toggle(isOn: alarmEntry.enabled)`. On other hand, takes input as Binding with Bool, and that's why it works.

Comment: Where did you learn to code in Swift? Any online class you followed?

Comment: I've worked for few years, upgrade day by day, reading some blog, wwdc video, etc. It takes time so relax xD.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a few dollar signs:

```
ForEach($alarmEntries) { $alarmEntry in
```

```
Toggle(isOn: $alarmEntry.enabled){
```

Answer (score -1):

This will Work Remove Dollar Sign

```
ForEach(alarmEntries) { alarmEntry in
    Text(alarmEntry.description)
    Toggle(isOn: $alarmEntry.enabled) {
        Text(verbatim: "This works...")
    }
}
```

Comment: I get _Cannot find '$alarmEntry' in scope_ with your solution

Comment: If I remove the $ sign I get this error:  Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Text' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'